# Why is the function shown in XDebug/kcachegrind as being called twice?

Tags: php, xdebug

When the php snippet below is invoked, in kcachegrind, the function aaa is called twice, and function bbb 4 times.

Can anyone explain why the function aaa gets called twice? Thanks.

```
<?php
echo "1111<br>\r\n"; 
aaa('Demo');

function aaa($p)
{
    echo 'current loop '.$p."<br>\r\n";
    for($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++){
        bbb($j);
    }
}

function bbb($p){
   echo 'bbb func loop: '.$p."<br>\r\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have four elements in your array and the for loop inside the aaa function is executed only 3 times so it calls again.